# "this.model" methods and filels in Anglular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I state that I can only use Angular 2+ (Angular4, Angular5, Angular6) and I don't know the old AngularJS almost at all.
Right now I'm translating part of an application developed in AngularJS to Angular 6.
In business logic code there are many methods and fieldset of the object `this.model`. Field such as: `this.model.$viewValue`; and method such as: `this.model.$setValidity` or `this.model.$setViewValue`.
The question is: how this "model object" works in AngularJS and how I translate it in a valid field in a TypeScript class in Angular 6?
Thanks.

Comment: Show some code. What is `this.model`? It's a component or controller property?

Comment: For example:
`this.model.$render = this.onModelRender.bind(this)`, where onModelRender is another method.

Comment: Those are methods and properties of the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).